# Activity не видит TextView в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragment, activity

> На главном экране есть FrameLayout, где, в зависимости от выбранного пункта меню, меняются фрагменты (экраны).

При попытке изменить из Activity текст во вложенном в фрагмент TextView вылетает ошибка `void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object`

Перепробовал разные варианты, но ничего не работает, везде аналогично.

Activity:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main");
    if(frag2!=null){
            Log.e("main", "fd");
        ((TextView)frag2.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.state_now)).setText("Ура");}else{Log.e("main", "Нет, не ура");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь найти текстовое поле не во фрагменте, но в активити. Надо как-то так:

`((TextView)frag2.getView().findViewById(R.id.state_now)).setText("Ура");}else{Log.e("main", "Нет, не ура");}`

Comment: frag2.getView() всегда возвращает null, хотя сверху есть проверка

Comment: @nikamon, видимо, вы слишком рано вызываете этот код. Чтобы `getView()` возвращал не `null` фрагмент должен быть добавлен в активити и его метод `onCreateView` должен отработать. Покажите где и когда вы этот код вызываете